# Nodejs : access socket.io instance in express routes files

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I would like to be able to emit datas to clients connected to socket.io server from my express routes files.

My **app.js** looks like this :

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

//routes
require('./routes/test')(app);

// starting http server
var httpd = require('http').createServer(app).listen(8000, function(){
  console.log('HTTP server listening on port 8000');
});

var io = require('socket.io').listen(httpd, { log: false });
io.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.join("test");
    socket.on('message', function(data){
       .....
    });
});
module.exports = app;
```

My **test.js** file :

```
module.exports = function(app){
    app.post('/test', function(req, res){
       .....
       //I would like here be able to send to all clients in room "test"
    });
};
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Simply inject your io object as an argument into the routes module :

**app.js** :

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();


// starting http server
var httpd = require('http').createServer(app).listen(8000, function(){
  console.log('HTTP server listening on port 8000');
});

var io = require('socket.io').listen(httpd, { log: false });
io.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.join("test");
    socket.on('message', function(data){
       .....
    });
});

//routes
require('./routes/test')(app,io);

module.exports = app;
```

**test.js** :

```
module.exports = function(app, io){
  app.post('/test', function(req, res){
    .....
    //I would like here be able to send to all clients in room "test"
    io.to('test').emit('some event');
  });
};
```

Comment: I never thought it was so simple.. All related posts were speaking about module export & other complicated stuffs.. Well you saved me ! Thank you!!

Comment: This worked great except I needed to check if io was valid first  'if (io) { io.to....}'